# What is correct: "will be not" or "will not be"?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, future

I was wondering if someone helps me and says which one is correct:

```
The function of feathers will be not restricted to flying
The function of feathers will not be restricted to flying
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, the second one.

The proper placement of negation in English is after the head of the verb phrase. With a simple verb, after that word. (He is not old-fashioned.) With a complex verb verb, after the modal or "helping" verb. (She has not arrived yet. They would not be silenced.)

Answer (score 0):

It's the second one. You could also say (in a more informal way) won't be